# What does "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" mean in an Odoo application?

Tags: python, window, odoo

I am facing below error in Odoo application:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\python.exe" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Odoo 12.0/server/odoo-bin" -c D:\config_odoo\config.txt -d Duy123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Odoo 12.0/server/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\graph.py", line 10, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 26, in <module>
    import werkzeug.utils
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\urllib2.py", line 220
    raise AttributeError, attr
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: i use version 3.8 bro

Comment: share the steps you performed to setup the Odoo application

Answer (score 0):

This is a general Python error. It's telling you that there's an error in your module's code.

According to the logs, it seems like you're trying to use a module written for an older Odoo version into 0doo 12. In general terms, that's a bad idea, and you're seeing why.